# How can I disable my Caps Lock key on macOS Sierra, without it resetting after a reboot?

Tags: keyboard, macos, caps-lock

For years, I’ve disabled my Mac’s caps lock key (because I only ever hit it by accident) in System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys.

Recently, I did a clean install of macOS Sierra on my 2014 MacBook Pro. Since then, my disabling of the caps lock key doesn’t seem to persist after reboots.

I found [an apparent report of the same issue on Apple’s forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7789807?start=0&tstart=0), and there are a few similar questions about previous versions of macOS:

- [Caps Lock key mapped to a second Control key, reset after wake in Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57774/caps-lock-key-mapped-to-a-second-control-key-reset-after-wake-in-mountain-lion)
- [How do I prevent my MacBook Air from forgetting my Remapped Caps Lock Key?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-do-i-prevent-my-macbook-air-from-forgetting-my-remapped-caps-lock-key)

But I don’t see an actual identified cause anywhere, nor a workaround.

Is this a bug? If so, how can I fix it?

If not, is there any way I can get the old, persistent behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with file permissions. Try this command in the Terminal (a built-in system tool):

```
chmod -RN ~/Library/
```

It resets permissions for your user Library folder. When the command is done executing, reboot. Change the setting and then reboot again, and see if the setting persists.

If it didn't work, then try this command:

```
chmod -RN /Library/
```

Yes, there is a difference: it resets permissions for the system’s Library folder.

Then reboot and change the setting as mentioned before, and see if it persists now.

Comment: “It could be a problem with file permissions” — could it? How?

Comment: Restoring from backup or doing software updates/install can give trouble with permissions . Unless you're a nerd that do give special permissions to each file, these commands shouldn't give any complications.

Comment: I wiped my Mac, installed Sierra on it, and manually copied over my files. I didn’t use any automated restore-from-backup procedure.

Comment: That could be the problem too, cause the files were copied over, some of them could still have the permissions of the older install...

Comment: Well sure, but I didn’t copy over System Preferences files. I copied files from my home directory, into my home directory. How are they meant to affect modifier key customisation settings in System Preferences?

Comment: Is there other settings that don't save?

Comment: Not that I’ve noticed, although obviously most settings aren’t as noticeable as the caps lock one. All the other keyboard Preferences seem fine. Dock does too. Date and Time are fine. Spotlight privacy doesn’t seem to remember to exclude my external backup drive, but for me that’s been true for as long as Spotlight’s been around.

Comment: I do still think the command will help

Comment: Is there any macOS problem which you think this command wouldn’t help?

Comment: Yes, a restart does solve most problems, but many other problems can be solved by changing stuff in the ~/library folder, sometimes is it permissions, other times can it be solved by removing a single file. I've had experienced an issue like yours twice, and both times did the command work.

Comment: Fair enough; I’ll test it on my computer when I get a chance to reboot.